# convert matlab.double into integer or float in python3

Tags: python, matlab

I have a package generated by Matlab to use in python. the output is something like this:

```
print(IdOut, 'len : ', len(IdOut))
# [[261.0],[263.0],[269.0],[274.0],[328.0],[769.0],[770.0],[772.0],[773.0],[774.0],[1959.0],[1962.0],[3189.0],[3542.0],[4385.0],[4422.0],[4780.0],[5148.0],[5546.0],[5967.0],[6188.0],[6480.0],[6533.0],[6776.0],[6778.0],[6779.0],[7011.0],[7012.0],[7978.0],[8244.0],[8245.0],[8246.0],[8247.0],[8248.0],[10262.0],[10606.0],[11036.0],[11896.0],[12049.0],[13355.0],[13356.0],[13526.0],[13805.0],[13921.0],[13962.0],[13965.0],[15264.0],[15535.0],[15795.0],[15950.0],[16411.0],[16414.0],[16415.0],[17265.0],[17772.0],[17853.0],[18072.0],[19098.0],[19373.0],[21392.0],[21787.0],[22531.0],[22849.0],[23126.0],[23127.0],[23128.0],[23674.0],[23691.0],[26278.0],[26923.0],[26933.0],[27441.0],[27442.0],[27705.0],[27708.0],[27710.0],[28172.0],[28294.0],[28297.0],[28934.0],[28944.0],[29019.0],[29265.0],[29270.0],[30825.0],[31939.0],[32072.0],[32605.0],[33085.0],[33397.0],[33398.0],[33612.0],[33615.0],[33620.0],[33871.0],[34502.0],[34930.0],[35500.0],[35977.0],[36137.0],[36197.0],[36564.0],[36579.0],[36801.0],[36802.0],[36803.0],[37154.0],[37714.0],[37744.0],[37845.0],[37852.0],[38186.0],[38365.0],[38366.0],[38497.0],[38508.0],[38555.0],[38556.0],[38560.0],[38571.0],[38572.0],[38573.0],[39400.0],[39401.0],[39702.0],[39703.0],[39704.0],[40110.0],[40385.0],[40573.0],[40796.0],[41625.0],[42124.0],[42376.0],[43095.0],[43207.0],[43219.0],[43449.0],[43598.0],[43847.0],[44298.0],[44950.0],[45033.0],[45242.0],[45267.0],[46017.0],[46264.0],[47060.0],[47427.0],[47545.0],[48024.0],[48836.0],[48935.0],[49231.0],[49232.0],[50277.0],[50338.0],[50584.0]] len :  158
```

when I ask for the type of `IdOut` the answer would be: `<class 'mlarray.double'>`.
and type of one of them for example `IdOut[0]` is : `<class 'mlarray.double'>`

```
>>> type(IdOut)
# <class 'mlarray.double'>
>>> type(IdOut[0])
# <class 'mlarray.double'>
>>> idout[0]
# matlab.double([261.0])
```

my problem is that I want these numbers in integer or floats. when I try I have these errors:

```
>>> float(IdOut[0])
# Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    float(IdOut[0])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'double'

>>> int(matlab.double([39400.0]))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    int(matlab.double([39400.0]))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'double'
```

can somebody tell me how I can convert and change the type of `mlarray.double` into floats or integers?
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `numpy.array`:

```
from numpy import array
a = array(IdOut)
print(a[0])
print(int(a[0]))
```

the output:

```
array([261.])
261
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this is helpful or not. but I can say if you convert your `mlarray.double` to an array from `numpy` library, then you can use it in the way you want.

```
import numpy as np
IdOut = np.array(IdOut)
```

now you can make a list of it in integers:

```
IdOut_list = [IdOut[i] for i in range(0, len(IdOut))]
```